# How to convert a string to an array based on values of another array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have some data that I'm trying to clean up.  For the field in question, I know what the possible values are, but the value is stored in a concatenated string and I need them in an array.  Here is what I would like to do:

```
var valid_values = ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'];
var raw_data = ['BarFoo','BazBar','FooBaz'];
desired_result = [['Bar','Foo'],['Baz','Bar'],['Foo','Baz']];
```

I'm not sure what this is called, so I hope this isn't a duplicate.

Comment: What happens to an invalid value?

Comment: What have you tried?  This just looks like you have to brute force loop through each `valid_values` item and do `.indexOf()` on each `raw_data` item and when you find something split the result on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over each data value, searching for allowed string with [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) or [contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains) and returning successful matches as array.

Here's my version of code and [working example at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JbUXA/):

```
var out = raw_data.map(function (raw) {
    return valid_values.filter(function (value) {
        return raw.contains(value);
    });
});

//out === [['Bar','Foo'],['Baz','Bar'],['Foo','Baz']];
```

I assumed that output match order isn't important.

Comment: This is perfect, and much cleaner than the spaghetti code I was writing.

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming some things about your data:

- you need to split strings into 2-item pairs
- input & terms are case-sensitive
- you won't be dealing with null/non-conforming inputs (requires more edge-cases)

In that case, you'd want to do something like this:

```
// for each item in the desired result, see if it's a match
// at the beginning of the string,
// then split on the string version of the valid value
function transform(input){
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      if (input.indexOf(valid_values[i]) === 0) {
          return [ valid_values[i], input.split(valid_values[i])[1] ];
      }
    }

    return [];
}

// to run on your input
var j = 0, raw_len = raw_data.length, desired_result = [];
for(; j < raw_len; j++) {
  desired_result.push(transform(raw_data[j]));
}
```

This code is pretty specific to the answer you asked though; It doesn't cover many edge cases.